# SQL column which is a list containing other rows

Tags: sql-server

I have a table which looks like this:

**Persons**

```
| Id | Name | FavoriteColor |
```

And I want to add a new column which is "Friends" so that it becomes

**Persons**

```
| Id | Name | FavoriteColor | Friends |
```

I want the `Friends` column to be (in abstraction) a list containing the Ids of other rows in the `Persons` table.

What's the best way to do this? I know I can use FK's to link up tables, but I'm not just linking a specific row to a specific row in a different table, but rather a specific row to a specific table.

Comment: You should ***never ever*** store multiple values into a single column - this is a horrible design, and violates even the **First Normal Form** of relational database design. Don't do it - ever. If you need to have an m:n relationship between two tables (or between the table and itself again), always use a "join" or "link" table to handle this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont add a field, you create a second table

```
 Persons: id, Name, Favorite Color
 Friends: PersonA_id, PersonB_id
```

Where PersonA_id, PersonB_id are Foreign Key to Persons table.

So you can have things like this in persons

```
 id     Name     Color
  1     Luis     Blue
  2     Pedro    Red
  3     Ana      Yellow
  4     Donald   Black
```

Friends:

```
PersonA_id PersonB_id
      1         2
      3         1
```

Luis have 2 friends, Pedro and Ana only have a friend (Luis), and Donald 0 friends.